# Inconsistent Cosmos DB graph RU cost for the same query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

We're using a CosmosDB Graph API instance provisioned with 120K RUs. We've setup a consistent partitioning structure using the `/partition_key` property.

When querying our graph using Gremlin, we've noticed that some queries use an unreasonably high amount of RUs when compared to other queries. The queries themselves are the same, but for the `partition_key` value itself.

The following query costs 23.25 RUs, for example:

```
g.V().has('partition_key', 'xxx')
```

Whereas the same query with a different `partition_key` value costs 4.14 RUs:

```
g.V().has('partition_key', 'yyy')
```

Looking at the `.exectionProfile()` results for both queries; they look similar.

The expensive query which costs 23.25 RUs (`xxx`):

```
[
  {
    "gremlin": "g.V().has('partition_key', 'xxx').executionProfile()",
    "activityId": "ec181c9d-59a1-4849-9c08-111d6b465b88",
    "totalTime": 12,
    "totalResourceUsage": 19.8,
    "metrics": [
      {
        "name": "GetVertices",
        "time": 12.324,
        "stepResourceUsage": 19.8,
        "annotations": {
          "percentTime": 98.78,
          "percentResourceUsage": 100
        },
        "counts": {
          "resultCount": 1
        },
        "storeOps": [
          {
            "fanoutFactor": 1,
            "count": 1,
            "size": 848,
            "storageCount": 1,
            "storageSize": 791,
            "time": 12.02,
            "storeResourceUsage": 19.8
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "ProjectOperator",
        "time": 0.15259999999999962,
        "stepResourceUsage": 0,
        "annotations": {
          "percentTime": 1.22,
          "percentResourceUsage": 0
        },
        "counts": {
          "resultCount": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The cheap query which costs 4.14 RUs (`yyy`):

```
[
  {
    "gremlin": "g.V().has('partition_key', 'yyy').executionProfile()",
    "activityId": "841e1c37-471c-461e-b784-b53893a3c349",
    "totalTime": 6,
    "totalResourceUsage": 3.08,
    "metrics": [
      {
        "name": "GetVertices",
        "time": 5.7595,
        "stepResourceUsage": 3.08,
        "annotations": {
          "percentTime": 98.71,
          "percentResourceUsage": 100
        },
        "counts": {
          "resultCount": 1
        },
        "storeOps": [
          {
            "fanoutFactor": 1,
            "count": 1,
            "size": 862,
            "storageCount": 1,
            "storageSize": 805,
            "time": 5.4,
            "storeResourceUsage": 3.08
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "ProjectOperator",
        "time": 0.07500000000000018,
        "stepResourceUsage": 0,
        "annotations": {
          "percentTime": 1.29,
          "percentResourceUsage": 0
        },
        "counts": {
          "resultCount": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The results both queries return a single vertex of about the same size.

Can someone please help explain why this is so? And why one is significantly more expensive than the other? Is there some aspect that I don't understand about Cosmos DB partitioning?

**Edit 1:**
We also did some experimentation by adding other query parameters, such as `id` and also `label`. An `id` clause did indeed reduce the cost of the expensive query from ~23 RUs to ~4.57 RUs. The problem with this approach is that in general it makes all other queries less efficient (i.e. it increases RUs).

For example, other queries (like the fast one in this ticket) go from ~4.14 RUs to ~4.80 RUs, with the addition of an `id` clause. So that's not really feasible as 99% of queries would be worse off. We need to find the root cause.

**Edit 2:**
Queries are run on the same container using the Data Explorer tool in Azure Portal. Here's the partition distribution graph: [image: partition distribution]

Comment: Could you pls do more test on query via partition key? The best situation is that you executed 2 queries and the only difference is partition key value, they all have one item as the result, then we may try to find the quantitative relationship. In my opinion, the conclusion we can draw now is that RU costs is base on the query result, and as you said the 'size' has a big gap. BTW, RU is defined as: The cost to do a point read (i.e. fetching a single item by its ID and partition key value) for a 1 KB item is 1 Request Unit (or 1 RU)

Comment: And this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units) may be helpful sir.

Comment: Have you got any progress or further testing sir? It's generous of you to share your case :)

Comment: @Tiny-wa I've updated with the latest findings...

Comment: Good day sir, it seems that you wanna find a way to reduce the RU cost, in my opinion it's equal to improve the performance, I recommend [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph-partitioning#graph-partitioning-mechanism) to you and hope it helps.

Comment: Couple questions that might help answering your question: Do you run queries on the same container? What is the average size of your logical partition (documents with the same partition key)? Where do you run your queries from and which SDK do you use?

Comment: @AnatoliiGabuza I've updated with some answers and the partition distribution graph. They do seem uneven, but I don't really understand why. All the partition keys we use are unique.

Answer (score 2):

The "issue" you're describing can be related to the size boundaries of physical partitions (PP) and logical partition (LP). Cosmos DB allows "infinite" scaling based on its [partitioning architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview). But scaling performance and data growth highly depends on logical partition strategy. Microsoft highly recommend to have as granular LP key as possible so data will be equally distributed across PPs.

Initially when creating container for 120k RUs you will end-up with 12 PP - 10k RUs limit per physical partition. Once you start loading data it is possible to end-up with more PP. Following scenarios might lead to "split":

- size of the LP (total size of data per your partition key) is larger than 20GB
- size of PP (total sum of all LP sizes stored in this PP) is larger than 50GB

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#partition-keys-for-read-heavy-containers)

```
A physical partition split simply creates a new mapping of logical partitions to physical partitions.
```

Based on the PP storage allocation it looks like you had multiple "splits" resulting in provisioning of ~20 PPs.
Every time "split" occurs Cosmos DB creates two new PPs and split existing PP equally between newly created. Once this process is finished "skewed" PP is deleted. You can roughly guess number of splits by PP id's on the Metrics chart you provided (you would have id: [1-12] if no splits happened).

Splits potentially can result in higher RU consumption due to request fan-out and cross-partition queries.

Comment: Interesting, so I guess this is a potential design issue in how it splits partitions. Any idea how to cause a more even split of partitions? Would that lead to more consistent RU consumption?

Comment: @infl3x go with smallest LP key possible (id, as an example). Then I'd expect to see similar consumption for both queries.

Comment: @infl3x re. "design issue" I would rather say it's a design choice targeted for infinite scale. And yes, it has drawback and might not be optimal for some use-cases.